# Primefaces Hotkey still working after leaving Dialog

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'm having difficulties using hotkeys with Primefaces.
After opening a Dialog, I would like to Show a Confirmation Dialog after an Escape Keypress.
The Main Problem is that after leaving the Dialog, this Escape button is still opening the Confirmation Dialog. Is there a way to bind this hotkey only to the Dialog? Is there some attributes from hotkey that i am not using for this?
This is the main code, taken from another stackoverflow answer, which unfortunately didnt correct
this issue.
Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>PrimeFaces Check</title>
    <style type="text/css">
</style>
</h:head>
<h:body> 
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="main content"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p:commandButton value="open Dialog"
            onclick="PF('dlgEdit').show();" />
            
            
<!--        Primefaces Dialog    -->
        <p:dialog id="dlgEdit" widgetVar="dlgEdit" width="500" height="500"
            closeOnEscape="true" closable="false" modal="true">
            <h:outputText value="dialog content"/>
            
           
         
            <p:hotkey bind="esc" handler="PF('confirmClose').show();" />
        </p:dialog>
         <p:confirmDialog message="Do you want to save?" widgetVar="confirmClose" width="250" height="250">
                <p:commandButton value="Yes"
                    oncomplete="PF('confirmClose').hide();PF('dlgEdit').hide();" />
                <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
                    onclick="PF('confirmClose').hide();PF('dlgEdit').hide();" />
        </p:confirmDialog>      
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7366

Comment: Also isn't HotKey global in the document and not constrained to the dialog once its registered.

Comment: can hotkey  be registered to a dialog or an input?

Answer (score 0):

I developed a solution for this issue. Is this going to give me an Exception or not work properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>PrimeFaces Check</title> 
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
    <style type="text/css">
</style>
</h:head>
<h:body> 
    <h:form>
    someinput 1
    <p:inputText  onkeydown="keyEventFuerTabShiftOderNurTabImInput();"/>
    <br/>
    someinput 2
    <p:inputText  onkeydown="keyEventFuerTabShiftOderNurTabImInput();"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
        <h:outputText value="main content"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p:commandButton value="open Dialog" process="@this"
            onclick="PF('dlgEdit').show();" />
            
<!--        Primefaces Dialog    -->
        <p:dialog id="dlgEdit" widgetVar="dlgEdit" width="500" height="500"
            closeOnEscape="false" closable="false" modal="true">
            <h:outputText value="dialog content"/>
            <p:ajax event="open" onstart="isDialogVisible('dlgEdit','confirmClose');"/>
        </p:dialog>
        
         <p:confirmDialog message="Do you want to save?" widgetVar="confirmClose" width="250" height="250">
                <p:commandButton value="Yes"
                    oncomplete="PF('confirmClose').hide();PF('dlgEdit').hide();" />
                <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
                    onclick="PF('confirmClose').hide();" />
        </p:confirmDialog>      
        
        <p:remoteCommand name="remotecommand" process="@this"
                 onstart="PF('checkdialog').show();" />        
               
    </h:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        keyEventFuerTabShiftImDialog();
    });
    
    function isDialogVisible(dialogId,confirmId){   
        $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27){
                var istDialogOpened = PF(dialogId).isVisible();
                if(istDialogOpened){
                    PF(confirmId).show();
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            }   
        });
    };
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    function keyEventFuerTabShiftOderNurTabImInput(){   
        if(event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 9) {
            //primefaces remote command  here possible:                             
            alert(("shift tab pressed"));
            return false; 
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == 9) { 
            //primefaces remote command  here possible:                             
            alert(("tab pressed"));
            return false; 
        }
    }
    /* ]]> */
    
    </script>
</h:body>
</html>
```